# Mac rebooting when in sleep

Tags: crash

After I installed the last macOS updates in December it has been rebooting at random times when in sleep as per below:

```
Feb  5 09:51:38 alisons-iMac MDCrashReportTool[921]: 921:66097152|CrashReportCopierAFC.m:-[CrashReportCopierAFC copyAndProcessRemotePath:usingConnection:]| ERROR: Could not remove remote path at ./WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-12-27-2017__07:29:35.log
Feb  5 09:51:38 alisons-iMac MDCrashReportTool[921]: 921:66097152|CrashReportCopierAFC.m:-[CrashReportCopierAFC copyAndProcessRemotePath:usingConnection:]| ERROR: Could not remove remote path at ./WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-12-29-2016__17:24:37.log
Feb  5 09:51:38 alisons-iMac MDCrashReportTool[921]: 921:66097152|CrashReportCopierAFC.m:-[CrashReportCopierAFC copyAndProcessRemotePath:usingConnection:]| ERROR: Could not remove remote path at ./WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-12-31-2017__09:26:50.log
Feb  5 09:51:54 alisons-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  5 09:55:16 alisons-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  5 10:00:27 alisons-iMac syslogd[61]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb  5 10:07:34 alisons-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Feb  5 10:10:31 alisons-iMac syslogd[61]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb  5 10:15:00 alisons-iMac timed[97]: settimeofday({0x5a782ea4,0xb889d}) == 0
Feb  5 12:19:30 alisons-iMac syslogd[61]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb  5 12:19:38 alisons-iMac netbiosd[1002]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?
Feb  5 12:26:14 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1517833574 0
Feb  5 12:26:50 localhost syslogd[61]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
        Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Feb  5 12:26:50 localhost syslogd[61]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
```

Any ideas please ?

Cheers

BTW it is running High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: I have the same issue. You can go down the Genius spiral, meaning contact Apple support and they will suggest non-solutions (like PRAM reset, reinstall, ...) for ages or you can just wait until it is fixed. Good luck.

Comment: If a `G`enius is suggesting you to reset the PRAM or the SMC without any idea of the source of the problem, leave him with a polite excuse (these religious resets are fixing bugs more than 20 years old when MacOS X was able to corrupt any of those components).

Comment: Could you add in your Original Question the version of MacOS X you are running now?

Comment: I have almost the same issue (not reboot, just forced logout), no solution yet. In logs I always get the same line just before the crash, so it's probably related: com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit

Comment: Can you run `$ pmset -g log` and paste the lines of the log from shortly before the last known good sleep through shortly after waking into the unexpectedly-rebooted state?